# CSS menu. Works on all browsers except IE

Tags: css, xhtml

i am trying to make a CSS menu for my webpage for school. I have been developing my site on a Mac and have got it working just the way i want it. I have tested it in safari, firefox and chrome as well as firefox on windows, all of these work fine, i hover over the links menu and it drops down.

css for menu

```
#menu
{
 position:relative;
 top:-83px;
 left:60%;
 font-size:30px;
 width:250px;
}


#menu ul
{
 position:absolute;
 list-style-type:none;
 background-image:url('../images/linkBG.png');
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position: 38px 0px;
 width:250px;
}

#menu li ul
{
 display:none;
 list-style-type:none;
 background-image:url('../images/menuBG.png');
 background-repeat:repeat-y;
 font-size:20px;
}


 #menu a:link {color:rgb(255,0,0);}
 #menu a:visited {color:rgb(255,255,0);}
 #menu a:hover {color:rgb(255,0,255)}
 #menu a:active {color:rgb(255,255,255);}

 #menu li:hover > ul
 {
 display: block;
 }

 #menu li ul li
 {
 padding-left:0px;
 padding-top:10px;
 padding-bottom:10px;


 }
```

When trying it on IE (ver6 and ver8) the links menu repositions it self (moves up about 50px and overlaps the heading), the background image gets moved across to the right by about 30px, and the menu no longer drops down when the mouse hovers over the text. I have heard of IE being a pain to develop for but this is just stupid. I have seen one solution that involved a bit of script to work around the issue but i cannot use script as this is for an assignment (which will be marked on a windows machine so there are high odds of it hitting IE). Along with the faulty menu is a table that i am centering using `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:auto` once again it works fine in all browsers except IE. Is there any way i can get around this? is there an alternative to hover that will work on all browsers.

thanks.

html code for menu

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Links Menu
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#info">Details</a></li><!--This may be #details-->
                <li><a href="#home_town_float">Home town</a></li>
                <li><a href="#course">My Course</a></li>
                <li><a href="#listdemo">Books, Music and Films</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabledemo">Timetable</a>     </li>
                <li><a href="#formdemo">Search</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Would be easier to help if you show your html

Comment: Added the HTML for the menu. I have fixed the table issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the margins and padding on your menu and the header above it.  IE sometimes misinterprets them when objects bordering each other have both margins and padding.  If you're able to replace your margins with more padding or different positioning, that might fix it.

Otherwise, the easiest way might to use IE conditional statements to give Explorer different versions of your CSS classes.  I doubt they'd be considered script, but I don't honestly know.  Example:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    #menu {
         /* different positioning for IE only */
         top: ____;
         left: ____;
    }
<![endif]-->
```